# Set default value when saving changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, .net-core-2.2

All my entities extend `BaseEntity` which has those (relevant) properties:

```
namespace Sppd.TeamTuner.Core.Domain.Entities
{
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Unique identifier identifying a single instance of an entity.
        /// </summary>
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Specifies when the entity instance has been created.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Specifies by whom the entity instance has been created.
        /// </summary>
        public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Specifies when the entity instance has been last updated.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime ModifiedOnUtc { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Specifies by whom the entity instance has been last modified.
        /// </summary>
        public Guid ModifiedById { get; set; }

        protected BaseEntity()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to let ef set the created/modified properties before saving. For this, I've added following when configuring the `DbContext`:

```
    private void ConfigureBaseEntity<TEntity>(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        // Constraints
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedOnUtc)
               .HasDefaultValueSql(_databaseConfig.Value.SqlUtcDateGetter)
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(e => e.ModifiedOnUtc)
               .HasDefaultValueSql(_databaseConfig.Value.SqlUtcDateGetter)
               .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
               .IsConcurrencyToken();
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedById)
               .HasValueGenerator<CurrentUserIdValueGenerator>()
               .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(e => e.ModifiedById)
               .HasValueGenerator<CurrentUserIdValueGenerator>()
               .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    }
```

And this `ValueGenerator`:

```
internal class CurrentUserIdValueGenerator : ValueGenerator<Guid>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override Guid Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        return GetCurrentUser(entry).Id;
    }

    private static ITeamTunerUser GetCurrentUser(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        var userProvider = entry.Context.GetService<ITeamTunerUserProvider>();
        if (userProvider.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            return userProvider.CurrentUser;
        }

        if (entry.Entity is ITeamTunerUser user)
        {
            // Special case for user creation: The user creates himself and thus doesn't exist yet. Use him as the current user.
            return user;
        }

        throw new BusinessException("CurrentUser not defined");
    }
}
```

When persisting the changes by calling `SaveChanges()` on the `DbContext`, I get following exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF.TeamTunerContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) in E:\dev\Sppd.TeamTuner\Backend\Sppd.TeamTuner.DataAccess.EF\TeamTunerContext.cs:line 48

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ModifiedById', table 'Sppd.TeamTuner-DEV.dbo.CardType'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

When checking the contents of the `ChangeTracker` all entities have the `ModifiedById` set:
[image]
Side note: The `ToList()` are required, otherwise it didn't enumerate correctly

Beside the fact that the IDs contain the value I expect, the `ModifiedById` property is not Nullable and thus should never be null (it might contain `default(Guid)`).

Any idea what's going on?

[Edit] Code to add:

Seeder:

```
internal class CardTypeDbSeeder : IDbSeeder
{
    private readonly IRepository<CardType> _cardTypeRepository;

    public CardTypeDbSeeder(IRepository<CardType> cardTypeRepository)
    {
        _cardTypeRepository = cardTypeRepository;
    }

    public int Priority => SeederConstants.Priority.BASE_DATA;

    public void Seed()
    {
        _cardTypeRepository.Add(new CardType
                                {
                                    Id = Guid.Parse(TestingConstants.CardType.ASSASSIN_ID),
                                    Name = "Assassin"
                                });
    }
        [...]
}
```

Repository:

```
namespace Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF.Repositories
{
    internal class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        protected DbSet<TEntity> Set => Context.Set<TEntity>();

        protected TeamTunerContext Context { get; }

        protected virtual Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> Includes { get; } = null;

        public Repository(TeamTunerContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Guid entityId)
        {
            TEntity entity;
            try
            {
                entity = await GetQueryWithIncludes().SingleAsync(e => e.Id == entityId);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException(typeof(TEntity), entityId.ToString());
            }

            return entity;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            return await GetQueryWithIncludes().ToListAsync();
        }

        public void Delete(Guid entityId)
        {
            var entityToDelete = GetAsync(entityId);
            entityToDelete.Wait();
            Set.Remove(entityToDelete.Result);
        }

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            Set.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            Set.Update(entity);
        }

        protected IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryWithIncludes()
        {
            return Includes == null
                ? Set
                : Includes(Set);
        }
    }
}
```

Commit the changes:

```
            if (isNewDatabase)
            {
                s_logger.LogDebug($"New database created. Seed data for SeedMode={databaseConfig.SeedMode}");

                foreach (var seeder in scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IDbSeeder>().OrderBy(seeder => seeder.Priority))
                {
                    seeder.Seed();
                    s_logger.LogDebug($"Seeded {seeder.GetType().Name}");
                }

                // The changes are usually being saved by a unit of work. Here, while starting the application, we will do it on the context itself.
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: are you getting the error in Insert or Update?

Comment: Insert. This happens when I seed data after having created the DB

Comment: Try setting the value of ModifiedById manually and see if the error moves to the next property

Comment: Without this, it works fine. I have used another way using EntityMetadataProviders setting these values in PrepareSaveChanges which didn't cause any issues. But it looked sexier to do it this way. As the error doesn't make sens to me I'd like to understand what's goping on and hopefully get it to work this way.

Comment: are you saying CreatedById works fine, and the error is only with ModifiedById?

Comment: No, I'll test your suggestion to remove the generator for ModifiedById and setting it as a constant a bit later. I expect the same exception on CreatedById

Comment: I hadn't thought to use a ValueGenerator to return the Id of the User this way. It's kind of cool, but maybe a misleading? What I mean by that is it seems like a ValueGenerator would be generating for generating a Key that didn't exist before. But, totally see where you are going. To handle this, I've always just overrode the SaveChanges Methods on  DbContext and used IoC to get a "User Service" that returns the current user (either via Property Injection or Service Locator).

Comment: @Matt.G I've followed your suggestion. It turns out that the issue originates from .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate(). If I change it to .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(), everything works fine. Looks like a framework bug to me; what do you think?

Comment: @SwampyFox I'm working on this project to get some core hands on, haven't got a lot of experience with it yet, so I'm always open to suggestions. Personally I think it's pretty nice, as I can set all those base properties in the EF configuration. The class name is also pretty self-explaining.

Comment: When registering the value generator twice for add and for update separately it's working fine as well.

Comment: That is interesting. so are you passing new instance of CurrentUserIdValueGenerator in HasValueGenerator?

Comment: I just pass the type, I didn't check how the framework instantiates it. There are two entries like this for add and update: builder.Property(e => e.ModifiedById).HasValueGenerator<CurrentUserIdValueGenerator>().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

Comment: Another interesting thing is that in the print-screen I've posted it says UPDATE failed, whereas it is an INSERT operation

Comment: Can you show your code to add?

Comment: @H.Herzl Sure, I've added it to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments and a lot of browsing in GitHub issues, it turned out that it isn't possible to use value generators for this. I've solved it by implementing a `PrepareSaveChanges()` in an override of `Datacontext.SaveChanges` which calls following code:

```
    private void SetModifierMetadataProperties(EntityEntry<BaseEntity> entry, DateTime saveDate)
    {
        var entity = entry.Entity;
        var currentUserId = GetCurrentUser(entry).Id;

        if (entity.IsDeleted)
        {
            entity.DeletedById = currentUserId;
            entity.DeletedOnUtc = saveDate;
            return;
        }

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entity.CreatedById = currentUserId;
            entity.CreatedOnUtc = saveDate;
        }

        entity.ModifiedById = currentUserId;
        entity.ModifiedOnUtc = saveDate;
    }
```

For the full implementation, follow the exectution path from the override of [SaveChangesAsync](https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/blob/80fb6a2a1d4b90ad0c4faa9b78297ce143e5700b/Backend/Sppd.TeamTuner.Infrastructure.DataAccess.EF/TeamTunerContext.cs#L53)